# Is Sandboxieplus safe against credential grabber?

Tags: sandbox

On the default settings, does https://sandboxie-plus.com/ protect against credential grabbers?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default it doesn't protect again reading (but not modifying) all your data but you can [configure](https://sandboxie-plus.github.io/sandboxie-docs/Content/ResourceAccessSettings.html) SandBoxie+ to allow only certain directories/disks which will make it impossible for malware to grab any secrets.

If you already have malware running on your system, SandBoxie+ is useless. This is an application for a known to be clean system.

Comment: Ok thanks i ran probably a credential grabber in sandboxie+ but i already changed all my passwords but sandboxie protects against modification of any files or did i missunderstood that too?

Comment: Under Sandboxie+ malware couldn't have caused any lasting damage (sandboxes are cleanly deleted) but you're right that you've changed your passwords. Passwords indeed may have leaked.

Comment: Yeah i changed all of them and i already had 2fa activated everywhere.